# WebRTC on cef3 with brackets-shell for windows application (HTML5)

Tags: html, webrtc, chromium-embedded, brackets-shell

I need to use the `navigator.getUserMedia()` function to use the webcam to take pictures on a windows application made with HTML5, and compiled on brackets-shell w/ cef3 (version 3.2171.1902).

Is this possible, or cef3 does not support webrtc at all?

I read online something about passing CEF command line arguments (`--enable-media-stream`) but I don't know where to put those commands...

Update:
I tried using nwjs instead of brackets-shell and it worked without any trouble.
http://nwjs.io/

Answer (score 0):

There are two overrides available that allow you to manipulate the command lines of the child processes, they are [CefBrowserProcessHandler::OnBeforeChildProcessLaunch](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefBrowserProcessHandler.html#OnBeforeChildProcessLaunch(CefRefPtr%3CCefCommandLine%3E)) and [CefApp::OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefApp.html#OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing(constCefString&,CefRefPtr%3CCefCommandLine%3E))

There is a nice short discussion here: ["How to pass additional command line arguments to subprocess"](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11659).

We use `OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing` to set command line options that could have been set on the args in main(), but weren't.  We use `OnBeforeChildProcessLaunch` to set arguments for child processes, such as command line arguments we did get in the arglist that we want propagated to our child processes.  One of these should do what you want.